# Mongodb: how to get "find" conditions from another collection?

Tags: mongodb

Just like this SQL do:

```
select * from t1 where id > (select id from t2 where name='abc')
```

Is it possible to accomplish this in one mongodb query?

Answer (score -1):

you should be able to use $lookup. $lookup is used to look up a document in another collection, it works more like a join. An example would be as below.

```
db.users.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
     from: "countries",
     localField: "country",
     foreignField: "_id",
     as: "cname"
  }
}])
```

in the above query you are matching records from user collection against countries collection on field country = _id.

you can then introduce a pipeline agreegator inside the lookup to apply the filter. An example for your reference that i picked from the mongodb documentation

```
db.orders.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "warehouses",
           let: { order_item: "$item", order_qty: "$ordered" },
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$stock_item",  "$$order_item" ] },
                         { $gte: [ "$instock", "$$order_qty" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              },
              { $project: { stock_item: 0, _id: 0 } }
           ],
           as: "stockdata"
         }
    }
])
```

you can find quite a good explanation and samples here on the official [MongoDB document for lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: Your examples don't really match the OP query.

Comment: i am just helping him with a sample. not the actual query itself. to write the actual query i would have to create the collections.

Comment: No, what I am saying is your sample is for a different query.  The OP specifically wants to know about  items in t1 where id is greater than a value in another table.  Your $lookup example does a direct match, not a greater than condition.  At best you are describing some capabilities of MongoDB Aggregation framework, but you are not providing any guidance to the OP for their particular problem.  Anyone else looking at this in the future will be confused by your answer.  Please create the actual query.  Please create the collections. Or, don't provide an answer because this one does not help.

Comment: ok let me try to create collections and try to recreate your actual sql in mongo. will keep you posted.